# How to pass a globally configured CDN url to templates in AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs, templates

this should be simple but after extensive googling I havent found an answer.

I use cloudfront as a CDN for my web app. I would like to configure the cloudfront url to a single file, as it might change in the future. I am trying currently to pass the value to the the templates as they use some images via css style background. I have found out that one solution would be to put in the scope in every controller, but there so many of them, and including this to all would make the code more possible for errors if it is forgotten.

So, this is a code example I have tried:

**app.js:**

```
.constant('CDNurl', 'https://xxxxxxxxxxx.cloudfront.net/')
```

**main.js:**

```
$rootScope.CDN = CDNurl;
```

**navbar.html:**

```
<div class="avatar__image" 
ng-style="{'background-image':'url(' + 
$root.CDNurl + currentUser.profileImage+')'}">;
```

does not work. If I include it in the navbar controller it of course works, but I need to pass it globally.

So what is the correct way of doing this? Configure something and reach it from templates?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a parent controller at the top of the DOM and in that you set `$rootScope.CDN = CDNurl;`, then you can access `CDNurl` is available in all the child views.

Or another option might be to use `run` (I haven't tried this):

```
var app = angular.module('module', []);

// run blocks
app.run(function($rootScope, CDNurl) {
   $rootScope.CDN = CDNurl;
});
```